# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at executeQuery

Tags: java, sql, csv, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I know there are lots of similar questions and I've read every one of 'em *(at least I believe so)* and I was not able to resolve my issue with the **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**. Let me describe my problem.

I'm working on a simple Java program which queries DB and generates a CSV file.

Everything was fine and I was able to generate CSV files for queries with huge data and with around **320+** columns.

And sometime later I faced this issue where I queried a table with exactly **309** columns.

Query is something like this `SELECT * FROM TABLE_A`. And it had no rows. So the query will return 0 records.

Ideally this should create a empty file which happens for all my other queries which I've tried except this one where I got this error and console pointed to this line where `executeQuery` is executed. Even with data in the table I get the same error.

The CSV is getting generated only when I explicitly increase the heap size to more than **3gb** whereas for others it was working with default heap size. *(no idea why it needs so much heap space for table containing 0 records)*

And for default heap size this particular report gets generated successfully only when I have less number of columns like **100-150** columns.

Why do I get the out of memory issue for this alone? Is there something to do with the table? To my knowledge the table is similar to all other tables. And will it be because of the column size for this table? For most of the columns I've **255** as the column size.

I've spent 2-3 days to analysis why this is happening and no luck.

Can someone help me out with this? I think this is not similar to any other out of memory issues out there. Its kinda weird.

Comment: Some code samples will be needed. It is not possible to extrapolate what could go wrong with only a few emphasized magic numbers. Also read [mcve].

Comment: What did you observe in the profiler?

Comment: Sounds like a potential error in the JDBC driver. Which JDBC driver are you using? Show the full stack trace, so we know exactly what you see.